# How Do I Grab the Number of Virtual Machines Running in a Node Pool using the CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Is it possible to find the number of running Compute Engine Virtual Machines (VM) that belong to a single Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) node pool using the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) SDK (`gcloud`) instead of the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After give some time I found out that there is no command to view no of nodes in node pools of GKE cluster through gcloud. But can be view using below command

```
kubectl get nodes -l cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=$POOL_NAME -o=name  --kubeconfig="$(pwd)/cluster" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

It **is** possible to find all Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Compute virtual machines (VM or `node`s) that belong to a node pool with the GCP SDK:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--filter="metadata.items[].filter(key:kube-labels).firstof(value):(cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=${GCP_NODE_POOL_NAME})"

#=>

NAME            ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
gke-. . .-wwww  us-central1-c  g1-small                   10.128.0.01  123.456.789.0  RUNNING
gke-. . .-xxxx  us-central1-c  g1-small                   10.128.0.02  123.456.789.1  RUNNING
gke-. . .-yyyy  us-central1-c  g1-small                   10.128.0.03  123.456.789.2  RUNNING
gke-. . .-zzzz  us-central1-c  g1-small                   10.128.0.04  123.456.789.3  RUNNING
```

The `--format` flag might make your node pool count easier:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--filter="metadata.items[].filter(key:kube-labels).firstof(value):(cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=${GCP_NODE_POOL_NAME})" \
--format="value(status)"

#=>

RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
```

Unfortunately, there currently does **not** seem to be a way to get a count of the current running nodes via the `node-pool` `gcloud` group:

```sh
gcloud container node-pools describe \
$GCP_NODE_POOL_NAME \
--cluster=$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
--format=json \
--zone=$GCP_NODE_POOL_ZONE

#=>

{
  "autoscaling": {
    . . .
    "maxNodeCount": 5,
    "minNodeCount": 2
  },
  . . .
  "initialNodeCount": 3,
  . . .
}
```

There is currently an open feature request to add a `currentNodeCount` or a `runningNodeCount` to the above response [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196248455).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a gcloud command to view no.of nodes that are running in nodepool of gke cluster.

The command for viewing no.of nodepools in gke cluster is

gcloud container node-pools list --cluster CLUSTER_NAME

The command for viewing no.of nodes in gke cluster u need to go for kubectl only.

kubectl get nodes

there is no command to view nodes in cluster by using gcloud .